# How to add post-fix to WordPress URL

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, url

I have situation where I would like to add a postfix to the WordPress URLs like 
http://www.example.com/post-name/MY_SLUG/

Here MY_SLUG is the identifier which needs to be added in each page, post or archive pages of WordPress. Bit confused on how to achieve this through .htaccess or custom rewrite rule.

Help from any one would really be appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: is `my_slug` a variable? or is it just the same slug throughout that you want added?

Comment: its a fixed string and not the dynamic variable.